# iOS apps that offer push notification interface (APN) via API

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, apns

I'm looking for a standalone iOS app, that can display APN's on my iPhone screen, by sending a request to their API.

Some of these seem to have existed in the past: Notifo, Howl and Prowl.  None of these seem to be active however.

Perhaps they might have been pulled down because of violations on Apple's ToS ?

Comment: Is IFTTT not an option? It's not *exactly* what you want, but it might get the job done.

Comment: I heard about IFTTT but haven't tested that one out yet.  Will do now.  Does it run as background process or does it display native APN?

Comment: I don't use their iOS app, so I wouldn't be able to speak to it, but I use their service for other things and automation. All I know is that at one point they had iOS notifications (not sure if they still do). If they don't still have notifications, they have a lot of other automation tasks that might work out just as good or better (SMS, email, etc).